# Yii Controller member variable scope

Tags: yii

Can we store in a YII controller inside its public member variable => some transient data like clicked div's id passed from javascript => for use in a view like modal ?

Example -
There is a partial view :

```
<div id="abc" ></div>
```

JS: -
When "abc" is clicked, then a request will be sent to Yii with this id as param
/controller/action/id/abc

### Controller: -

Member var:-
public $transientIdData;

inside action, id = abc is read and then I set that id in a member variable :- 
$transientIdData = "abc"

### View:-

Another partial view like fancybox has to get this id and will be called after click by JS. It can get from Controller's member variable transient data for Id clicked just now.

So my questions -

```
(i) Can we save such per request data in Yii Controller's member var. 
(ii) Is there a better pattern for achieving this behaviour
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Understand that HTML requests are themselves stateless. Therefore one page request is not related to the next.

Therefore, when page1 is rendered, the controller has already completed execution. When you interact with page1, your web page is not connected to the controller. Therefore you must send this using Ajax, as you indicated, effectively sending another request for the page 'action'.

You can connect these 2 page requests by using sessions. Therefore, you action will read

```
function actionAction() {
   Yii::app()->session['transientIdData'] = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id', NULL);
}
```

Later (for example in another page request), you can access the variable

```
   echo Yii::app()->session['transientIdData'];
```